# writing binary values into file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, binary

i was converting an image file into binary to process in VHDL. while i was converting image to binary and when writing that matrix into a text file unnecessary commas came between the number.I want a column vector.my input is a square matrix.all working well except the comma part.i am using dummy values.can anyone give any suggestions

```
a=[1 3;6 9];
b=dec2bin(a');
fName = 'output.txt';
fid = fopen('output.txt','w');
dlmwrite(fName, b);
```

but the output file was like this

```
0,0,0,1
0,0,1,1
0,1,1,0
1,0,0,1
```

i was  expecting

```
0001
0011
0110
1001
```

Comment: Check [fwrite](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html).

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass `''` as an delimeter . Ref:- [dlmwrite usage](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)

```
dlmwrite('output.txt', b, '')
```

Comment: but the values are changed..now its displaying
0001
0010
0110
1101

Comment: @user2689061 ahh, sorry I took transpose of b `(b')`, updated