# Write binary number to text file [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

I want to create an input file with random 8 bit binary number for VHDL testbench using Matlab.

```
%create random 10 decimal number
a = randi ( [0 255], 10 , 1 ); 
display(a);
%convert to 8bit binary
a=dec2bin(a,8);
display(a); 
%write to textfile
fid=fopen('eventsIn.txt','wt'); 
fprintf(fid,'%s\n',a); 
fclose(fid);
```

how i want to make sure that the output become

```
1010100
1100100
0010100
0111101
0000110
```

instead of this format?

```
10101001100100001010001111010000110010011110111000101011101101101110100100100010
```

Comment: Did you open it with note pad or notepad++? Or anyother depending on OS.

Comment: I'm using windows and have tried both notepad and notepad++..but still give a single line output

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing binary values into file in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271253/writing-binary-values-into-file-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with your approach, only changing two things:

1. If each *row* of `a` is a number which should be written in a different line, you should transpose `a` before feeding it to `fprintf`. That's  because `fprintf(fid,'%s\n',x)` reads first *column* of `x`, then second column etc.
2. Add a carriage return (ASCII code 13) or line feed (ASCII code 10) or both at the end of each column of `a.'` (that is, in a new row or two new rows). And as a side result you don't need the `\n` in the format string of `fprintf`.

So, use

```
fprintf(fid, '%s', [ a.'; repmat(char(13), 1, size(a,1)) ] ) %// CR only
```

or

```
fprintf(fid, '%s', [a.'; repmat(char([10; 13]), 1, size(a,1))] ) %// LF and CR
```

Comment: Hm, but this way you end each line with a CR, and at the very end you have an additional LF?!

Comment: @A.Donda Thanks, now I see what you mean. I have removed `\n` from the format string

Comment: @khairul Please consider marking one of the answers as "accepted", if it does what you want

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

First try this:

```
dlmwrite('output.txt', b, '')
```

---

What you currently seem to do is writing all data and then appending a newline.

There are several ways to deal with this.
This is a simple one:

Do your writing in a for loop over the lines and append a newline after each line.

If that still doesn't work you can try using `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` is a two-dimensional character array, that you would like to be interpreted as a sequence of strings. However, `fprintf(fid,'%s\n',a)` just handles it as one big string. As Dennis Jaheruddin writes, there are several ways to achieve this. I think this one's pretty simple:

Convert the two-dimensional character array into a cell array of strings:

```
a = cellstr(a);
```

Feed it to `fprintf` as an (implicit) sequence of arguments:

```
fprintf('%s\n', a{:})
```

This way, you don't need to program a loop.